# How do I get my XSLT to only run on a list of QIDs?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have my script performing the way I want but I only want it to run on certain files.

I need to be able to input a list so the script will only run when it matches the number in the data-value field in the code below. Otherwise I don't want it to run. The way is have it currently isn't working.

```
<span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="NCQ0264"></span>
```

This is my script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- provide QID -->
    <xsl:param name="QIDlist">NCQ0264</xsl:param>
    <!-- use to pinpoint selected QIDs for transformation -->
    <xsl:variable name="input-qid" select="tokenize($QIDlist, '\s+')"/>


    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/@class[.='atom-exclude']">

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: From inside of an XSLT program you can't prevent that it is run, you would have to do that from the outside. What you can do is have the XSLT not create any output by for instance using `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="node()[//span[@property = 'atom:content-item-name' and @class = 'ktp-meta' and @data-value = $input-qid]"/></xsl:template>`. Or you could check that condition and if it is not true use `xsl:message terminate="yes"`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, Martin! That definitely helped. I posted a revised script below and a new question. I'm very raw with XSLT so your help is most appreciated..

Comment: It is not clear which input you have and which output you want, as your original request sounded like you wanted to produce no content at all if the condition is not met I put it in there in the root template. Your response sounds like you want to produce some content in any case but only produce part of the output based on the condition. So you will need to move the condition to a template or pattern you need it applied, if you need help with that then edit your question and show us minimal but representative types  of input/output samples.

Comment: Basically if that identifier is not present I don't want the transform to run so the file should remain as is and untouched. The only time I need the transformation to run is when the identifier is present. How do I adjust the script so the file remains as is unless the identifier is there?

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress thanks to Martin's response.

The way I have it now the script is running properly when the identifier number is present but when the identifier is not present it's deleting all content on the page. How can I fix that?

Here's my current script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- provide location of update table -->
    <xsl:param name="QIDlist">NCQ0866</xsl:param>
    <!-- use to pinpoint selected QIDs for transformation -->
    <xsl:variable name="input-qid" select="tokenize($QIDlist, '\s+')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="node()[//span[@property = 'atom:content-item-name' and @class = 'ktp-meta' and @data-value = $input-qid]]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/@class[. = 'atom-exclude']"> </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="h1/@class[. = 'atom-exclude']"> </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm trying to make a global change where the atom-exclude class is removed from these paragraphs:

```
<p class="atom-exclude">1) <span class="mark-false">INCORRECT</span> – The nurse should not start the series over again. The hepatitis B immunization is a set of three injections. The children should be scheduled for the second and third injections.</p>
```

And these H1s:

```
<h1 class="atom-exclude">Think Like a Nurse: Clinical Decision-Making</h1>
```

But only on certain questions that have a specific content-item-name data-value:

```
<section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta"><span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="NCQ0866"></span></section>
```